# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor giving ConnectionPoolTimeOutException

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot

Getting this error even though the total count of active thread is less than the corepoolsize.

ThreadPool which I have created :

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1500);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2000);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MakeShoppingRequest");
    executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(10);
    executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    executor.initialize();
```

Exception:

```
**org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Timeout waiting for connection from pool; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool**
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:316)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:282)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.ClientHttpRequestConnection.onSendAfterWrite(ClientHttpRequestConnection.java:83)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:48)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:658)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: that is `http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException:` http pool connection timeout not thread timeout

Comment: Thanks the issue got resolved I needed to increase the http connection timeout  in my project.